# Improvements for code to decrease compilation time

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar,colormaps}
\pagecolor{black}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
background rectangle/.style={
    inner color=violet!70!black,
    outer color=black
},
show background rectangle
]
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      domain  = -14400:14400,
      samples = 500,
      hide axis,
      colormap/violet
    ]
    \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {sin(.5*x)};
    \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {sin(.2*x)};
    \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {sin(3*x)};
        \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {1-sin(.5*x)};
        \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {1-sin(.2*x)};
        \addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=0.5] {1-sin(3*x)};
    \end{polaraxis}
  \node[below left=.1cm,white] at (current bounding box.north east) {\textcolor{violet}{I}nspiration};
%  \node[black] at (current bounding box.south) {
%   \begin{tabular}{rl}
%   \textit{by} & \\
%   & \textsc{MY NAME}
%   \end{tabular}
%  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
background rectangle/.style={
    inner color=orange!80!black,
    outer color=black
},
show background rectangle
]
\begin{polaraxis}[
domain  = -14400:14400,
samples = 5000,
hide axis
]

\addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=.5] {1-sin(2*cos(x/(sin(x)+1))*x)};
\addplot[no markers,mesh,opacity=.5] {sin(2*cos(x/(sin(x)+1))*x)};

\end{polaraxis}
\node[below left=.1cm,white] at (current bounding box.north east) {\textcolor{orange}{C}reativity};
%\node[white] at (current bounding box.south) {
%   \begin{tabular}{rl}
%   \textit{by} & \\
%   & \textsc{MY NAME}
%   \end{tabular}
%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
background rectangle/.style={
    inner color=blue!30!black,
    outer color=black
},
show background rectangle
]
\begin{polaraxis}[
domain  = -14400:14400,
samples = 5000,
hide axis
]

\addplot[colormap/cool,no markers,mesh,opacity=.5] {x*sin(x)+x*cos(x/2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\node[below left=.1cm,white] at (current bounding box.north east) {\textcolor{blue}{C}reation};
%\node[black] at (current bounding box.south) {
%   \begin{tabular}{rl}
%   \textit{by} & \\
%   & \textsc{MY NAME}
%   \end{tabular}
%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is: How can be the code simplified/improved to make the compilation faster (of course it depends on the computer and the machine, but I mean in generally …)

Comment: you can use tikz externalize so you only need to generate the image once and after than include the ready typeset version, but I'm nit sure that's the answer you are looking for....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming gnuplot installed, you can replace all \addplot […] with \addplot […] gnuplot and compile with shell-escape.

compiling  Debian  on Asus X205TA (very cheap machine)

**$ time pdflatex tex-ecm-Ia6t.tex # your mwe**
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.

[snip]
real    3m43,067s
user    3m42,941s
sys 0m0,210s

**$ time pdflatex -shell-escape tex-ecm-Ia6t.tex # my mwe with gnuplot**
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.

[snip]
real    2m4,887s
user    2m4,431s
sys 0m0,466s

**$ time pdflatex -shell-escape tex-ecm-Ia6t.tex   #with \usetikzlibrary{external}  \tikzexternalize**

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.

[snip]
real    0m2,241s
user    0m2,028s
sys 0m0,204s